# Double precision SIMD random generator with normal distribution for AVX, AVX2 and AVX512?

Tags: random, double, avx, avx2, avx512

After some research I'm not able to find a vectorized double precision random generator (best would be normal distribution), using AVX, AVX2 or AVX512.

How can/should that be done in C++, for vectors of `n` `double`s
(`__m128d` / `__m256d` / `__m512d`)?

Ideally something to learn SIMD FP techniques from, so simpler is preferable.

Comment: Check FastNoise2 library. It has 100M/s random open simplex noise performance on Fx8150 cpu and benchmarks show 800M/s for a new cpu.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear: actually, i cannot found any double precision random generator based on avx. Okay, for a uniform distribution, could it work to concat two 32bit floats? but this approach would not work for normal distribution.

Comment: "Is anyone able to post a minimal working example... in C++"—please take the [tour]. That's not what we do here.

Comment: Well, MRG32k3a is an obvious candidate for vectorization, given that it is a linear operation that generates variate n+8 from variate n. There is a **RNGAVXLIB** library that includes it. Papers: [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465515004117](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465515004117)  and  [https://publications.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/share/folder/0uv4q564kx/direct/204282243.pdf](https://publications.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/share/folder/0uv4q564kx/direct/204282243.pdf).